# where was the ark of the covenant during the time of the judges?

Tags: history, ark-aron-kodesh, mishkan-tabernacle, shoftim--book-of

After Joshua, during the time of the judges, where was the ark located? In [Judges 18](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0718) it seems that the people did not have a central place of worship.

Comment: Why do you think Judges 18 implies that? (Note, in particular, its last words.)

Comment: 31. And they set them up Micah's graven image, which he made, all the time that the house of G-d was in Shiloh.

Comment: so, is this saying that the house of G-d was in Shiloh the whole time it's just that people were not going to it? So, the Ark was being kept in Shiloh?

Comment: Obviously, at least part of the period of the judges, the _mishkan_ (house of God) was in _Shilo_. Whether it was there the whole time or not is a fine question (and is essentially equivalent to yours, above), but my point was that Judges 18 is a poor choice of support for your assertion that "the people did not have a central place of worship" because (besides the fact that it doesn't say so) it says the opposite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mishnayot in the [last chapter of Zevachim](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h51.htm) outline the journey of the Tabernacle. When the Jews arrived in Israel:

- The Tabernacle was in **Gilgal** for the 14 years of capturing and dividing the land.
- It then moved to **Shiloh** for 369 years.
- When Shiloh was destroyed (I Samuel 4), the Tabernacle was moved to **Nov** until it too was destroyed (I Samuel 22:19)
- whereupon it was moved to **Givon** until the building of the first **Temple in Jerusalem** by King Solomon.

The Ark, meanwhile:

- had been taken from Shiloh when it was destroyed **by the Philistines**. It was in their hands for 7 months (I Samuel 5:1)
- then it was returned to the Jews at **Beit Shemesh** (I Samuel 6:13) who placed it into care in **Kiryat Ye'arim** (I Samuel 6:21).
- It stayed there until King David brought it up to **Jerusalem**, stopping temporarily at the **house of Oved Edom the Gittite** (II Samuel 6:10).

Comment: Thank you! Do you by chance know any good books on the subject..?

Comment: I thought it was in Shiloh, too, but Judges 20:26-28 says the ark was at Bethel and Eleazar, father of Phinehas (the same as Eli from 1 Samuel, where the ark is in Shiloh?) was ministering before it. I'm confused.